# How to use custom native java classes / functions in nativescript?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

So my manager seems to think that converting an app from 2 fully native iOS and Android apps, to one cross-platform angular/nativecript app is a straightforward task (it sounds like a terrible idea to me). Im trying to research the effort required to do this. Ive created a helloworld nativescript app and im trying to see what the best way of integrating existing native code into a nativescript app is (basically i want to have access to my native webservice functions). My knowledge on this subject is severely limited.

Ive seen there is a way to [make your own native packages](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/plugins-and-jars) that can be used, but this seems like it would be way to much effort and cumbersome/messy. Is there no way to just access a custom native java object inside nativescript? for example:

```
//Java
package com.tns;

public class TestObject {
    public String doSomething () {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

---

```
//Nativescript
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

declare var com: any

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ActionBar title="My App"></ActionBar>
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <Label [text]="message" (tap)="onTap()"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public message: string = "Hello, Angular";
    public onTap() {
        this.message = "Text Changed";
        var test = new com.tns.TestObject();
        console.log(test.doSomething());
    }
}
```

edit: for future readers, the above code is in fact working now

I know you [can do it](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript) with just normal Android classes, but havent been able to do it with my own custom classes, maybe im just missing something though (something to do with imports maybe?).

I am getting this error when trying to run the program

```
app/app.component.ts(21,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'com'.
```

and I have my object just under the main folder in my project

[image: screenshot]

Basically they want us to convert certain sections of the android app to nativescript at a time while leaving all the old native functionality in tact, so that eventually the whole project will be converted to nativescript, and thus one code base for both ios and android theoretically. Sounds like a really bad way to go about it, should just start from scratch imo.

**TL;DR**

How to use custom java class in nativescript code?

----- Additions from comments ------

> An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException:  Calling js method onTouch failed
>
> [object Object] File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.HelloWorld/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/gestures/gestures.js,
>   line: 97, column: 40
>
> StackTrace: 
>       Frame: function:'GesturesObserver.androidOnTouchEvent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.HelloWorld/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/gestures/gestures.js',
>   line: 97, column: 41
>       Frame: function:'onTouch', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.HelloWorld/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view.js',
>   line: 113, column: 37
>
> ```
> at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
> at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1197)
> at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1061)
> at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1047)
> at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1028)
> ...
> ```

Comment: If you bring the custom files into the project what you have here `var test = new com.tns.TestObject()` should indeed work. Does the `log(test)` actually output anything? As for your angular portion, is any of this going to be used on a web version? If not, I'd skip the angular piece and use plain NativeScript. There are pros/cons both ways for sure but if it's never going to be on the web, you don't gain anything with having angular in your nativescript app. Nothing that would sway me anyway :)

Comment: @BradMartin Ive updated my question with some more info, im also editing my .ts file that is the main native script project folder as well, not under platforms/android/ etc FYI. Not going to be using any web component with the code, so thanks for your suggestion

Comment: That's a TS error, nothing to do with nativescript at that point. So you have a couple options in handling the TS compiler. Set `noEmitOnError:false` in tsconfig.json for the project. This will allow the compiler to emit even with errors. Or you can put above the export,  `declare var com: any` so TS knows com is just the type `any` There are more options in handling but that should help. TS errors are prefixed with `TS` so, `TS2304` indicates a TS warning/error. No major road block with that :)

Comment: The NativeScript team also has android and iOS typescript typings to help with intellisense and informing TS of the native classes,methods,props, etc. so the compiler doesn't bark so much. You can add those with `npm install tns-platform-declarations` I think. They have another tool that attempts to generate TS typings for custom java/android libraries/modules added to your project. I haven't used it though.

Comment: This (https://github.com/NativeScript/android-dts-generator) might be the tool and I believe it happens during the `build` step of a nativescript app via a flag passed on that command. I could be wrong about that link ^^ it may be part of the NS CLI now, sorry I really haven't used it so not sure. On another note you might find some great help on the NS slack channel, always good info and helpful people there. Plus the NS forums at forums.nativescript.org I believe might help if you do end up making a POC for your manager.

Comment: I think this is a decent sample of using native libs with nativescript, https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-lottie/blob/master/nativescript-lottie.android.ts#L11 published it today. You'll see a few things I do to make TS compiler happy.

Comment: Ok i did as you suggested by going `noEmitOnError:false` and  `declare var com: any` which let it compile, but im getting a crash now, and the exception error isnt very useful, just saying to crashing in the onTouch in file gestures.js, which im assuming is related to on onTap() method ive got and crashing in there. Im going away from my computer for a bit, so ill only be able to reply in a while, but if you have any other suggestions please do leave them here, thanks a lot for this info.

Comment: 1030pm here, calling it a night. Please add the exception and it'll help to see what's wrong and any code you have involved. Add that to the question and I'll help you out :) If you get on the slack channel, ping me there also. nativescript.org - green slack button should get you an invite :)

Comment: @BradMartin ok ive added the log, it is definitely crashing on the line `var test = new com.tns.TestObject();`. also is there a way so that each object doesnt have to be prefixed by `com.tns` etc?

Comment: ok it seems to be working now, Im not sure what I did, could just be a case of it needing to rebuild something. Thanks for your help! the question still stands about the `com.tns` part though, seems like it could be quite tedious and code bloating having that kind of stuff everywhere, especially when the java files are quite well nested in folders

Comment: if you want to just copy paste some of your comments into an answer ill award you the answer cause you got to the core of the problem first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @Brad Martin explained in the comments, all you need is to declare what `com` is and you will be able to use the java file in your nativescript code without any hassle

```
//Java
package com.tns;

public class TestObject {
    public String doSomething () {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

---

```
//Nativescript
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

declare var com: any //this is the important part

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ActionBar title="My App"></ActionBar>
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <Label [text]="message" (tap)="onTap()"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public message: string = "Hello, Angular";
    public onTap() {
        this.message = "Text Changed";
        var test = new com.tns.TestObject(); //cant use this without the declare above
        console.log(test.doSomething()); //will print "hello" in the console
    }
}
```

Where my java file is located in the android project:

[image: File location in Android project for reference]

Comment: Somehow I am getting "it is not a function" error after I update the java file. So combined copied the file automatically to the platforms seems solved this issue. From here : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1577

Comment: Hello Fonix, I try your post in my app, and show this error: `JS: ERROR TypeError: com.tns.TestObject is not a constructor` and `JS: ERROR ONTEXT {JS:   "view": {JS: "def": {JS: "nodeFlags": 34262017,JS: "rootNodeFlags": 3554433,JS: "nodeMatchedQueries": 0,JS: "flags": 0,JS:  "nodes": [JS: {JS:           "nodeIndex": 0,JS:           "parent": null,
JS:  "renderParent": null, JS: "bindingIndex": 0,JS: "outputIndex": 0,JS:   "checkIndex": 0,JS:   "flags": 33554433,JS: "childFlags": 49152,JS:  "directChildFlags": 49152,JS:   "childMatchedQueries": 0,JS:  matchedQueries": {},JS:    ...`

Comment: @Fonix can you  help me please?

Comment: @Aulonna I dont know what that error could be unfortunately, havnt touched angular in a long time

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Try exclude those round brackets :) Same thing to assigning classes i am using at plugin.</strike>

**EDIT**

It should be with those brackets :D

```
var test = new com.tns.TestObject();
console.log(test.doSomething());
```

Comment: Hmm strange, i got it to work, but it wasnt because of the round brackets, i dont actually know what did the trick because it doesnt seem like I've changed anything important, but you are sort of correct, it doesnt actually need the round brackets, but it still works with them...

Comment: Yeah, after checking whole code i was like `ehm what ?`  And about those not needed prefixed, `var ArrayList = java.util.ArrayList;` and then only need to call is `var list=new ArrayList();`

Comment: ah awesome, would there be a way to sort of globally define things like that in the project, or have to do it on a per file basis?

Comment: Probably you can one file eand export each these prefix variables and import them when needed

Comment: can we at least declare it in the file scope somehow? ive tried going `declare var TestObject: com.tns.TestObject` but that doesnt work, cant find "com" again, although the com was declared above it with `declare var com: any`

Comment: Oh not declare you need to assign as variable content, `var ct=com.tns` and then you can use `var ct.TestObject`

Comment: oh sorry, thought you could only do that in the scope of a class, yep that is working thanks

Comment: Please fix the code sample by calling the constructor function TestObject. the above could would normally fail.

Also @Fonix, if you wish to consume classes I'd suggest you package them in an aar or a jar, as that way you can make them persistent across builds. Unlike now - placing the files in platforms/android will guarantee a wipe during a rebuild/reinstallation, and you dont want that.

Comment: @pkanev Unfortunately that isnt really possible in my situation, my native script code will be going into an already existing android project, so not sure if that is really possible with the way the android project is structured